# Where do I configure ActiveRecord when creating a gem?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, bundler

I'm creating a gem that I've built with `bundle gem GEMNAME`. I'm following some instructions to use ActiveRecord in my Gem, and it's telling me to put some configuration in my `app/main.rb` file:

```rb
require 'active_record'
require_relative './models/movie'

def db_configuration
  db_configuration_file = File.join(File.expand_path('..', __FILE__), '..', 'db', 'config.yml')
  YAML.load(File.read(db_configuration_file))
end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_configuration["development"])
```

But I know the file structure of a gem is different and important, and bundler didn't build me an `app` folder, which I'm assuming is for a good reason.

So where do I put this file/code?

Comment: Only you can know where to put initialization code for your gem, since only you know how you structure your gem.

Comment: Well I'm just using the folder structure that `bundle gem gemname` gave me.

Answer (score 1):

When building gems, extending active record, it's better not to configure it by yourself. Gem users will include your gem and probably have own database configuration.

Thus, your gem should not configure host application or connect to database. But you can do it in tests.

Usually you just need to define Rails Engine in your gem and use dummy app for testing. It worth reading this guide [Getting Started with Engines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). It describes how to extend rails app in your library.

For example of gem, extending host app check out my gem https://github.com/bolshakov/activeadmin_sortable_table

Comment: Thanks but the gem I’m writing is a command line tool, not a gem to be included in others’ programs.

Comment: In that case, you should have `bin/gem_name` executable. I think it's good place to configure database connection using command line options instead of config file.

Comment: While the Rails engines guide referenced in this answer might be a good read to get the fundamentals, there is now another guided about creating Rails plugins specifically which might be more practical in this case: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html